# Error definiciones múltiples al declara variable estatica

Tags: c++

Tengo el archivo a.h de la siguiente manera

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
//#include <iostream>
class Clase
{
private:
    static int numero;
public:
    void mostrar();
};
int Clase::numero = 3;

#endif
```

El archivo a.c++ que solo contiene (Comente el cout para mostrar el preprocesado mas corto)

```
#include "a.h"

void Clase::mostrar() {
    //std::cout << numero << "\n";
}
```

Y el archivo b.c++

```
#include "a.h"

int main() {
    Clase c;
    c.mostrar();
}
```

Cuando compilo me dice que estoy redefiniendo la variable `Clase::numero` creo que me esta fallando el `#ifndef A_H` algo estoy haciendo mal y no me doy cuenta, este es el código al compilar con `g++ a.c++ b.c++ -E`

```
# 1 "a.c++"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "a.c++"
# 1 "a.h" 1
class Clase
{
private:
    static int numero;
public:
 void mostrar();
};
int Clase::numero = 3;
# 2 "a.c++" 2

void Clase::mostrar()
{

}
# 1 "b.c++"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "b.c++"
# 1 "a.h" 1
class Clase
{
private:
    static int numero;
public:
 void mostrar();
};
int Clase::numero = 3; //<---- Aquí lo vuelve a poner y produce el error
# 2 "b.c++" 2

int main() {
    Clase c;
 c.mostrar();
}
```

En el código anterior se puede ver que esta incluida 2 veces la clase y obviamente se esta redefiniendo la variable, pero se supone que no debería pasar eso.

Este es el error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLBddsD.o:(.data+0x0): definiciones múltiples de `Clase::numero'; /tmp/ccHpssAu.o:(.data+0x0): primero se definió aquí
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La inicialización de las variables estáticas debe realizarse en el cpp. Si lo haces en la cabecera todos los archivos que incluyan la cabecera tendrán una inicialización de la misma variable y eso al compilador no le gusta demasiado.

**`a.h`**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
//#include <iostream>
class Clase
{
private:
    static int numero;
public:
    void mostrar();
};

#endif
```

**`a.c++`**

```
#include "a.h"

int Clase::numero = 3;

void Clase::mostrar() {
    //std::cout << numero << "\n";
}
```

Claro que al ser una variable estática y privada resulta que no hay necesidad alguna que justifique que esa variable deba estar declarada en la cabecera. Puedes mover declaración e inicialización al cpp y evitas la *"innecesaria necesidad"* de que todo el mundo tenga que saber que esa variable existe:

**`a.h`**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
//#include <iostream>
class Clase
{
public:
    void mostrar();
};

#endif
```

**`a.c++`**

```
#include "a.h"

// namespace anónimo para garantizar que la variable solo existe en este cpp
namespace  
{
  int numero = 3;
}

void Clase::mostrar() {
    std::cout << numero << "\n";
}
```

Comment: ¿ya no es necesario que sea declarada como static dentro de namespace?

Comment: @Carlos no, no es necesario. En la clase sí para distinguir una variable *global* dentro de la clase de una variable miembro... pero dentro del `namespace` no es necesario